# re-embed subset font in pdf with itext 7

Tags: java, itext7

I have some input PDF all with full set fonts, I want to "shrink" them all creating fonts subset. I know there is the way to [unembed fonts](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/unembed-font) and [embed subset font](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-embed-font-only-partially), but the problem is that i don't have the source file of fonts. I just have fonts embedded in source PDF.

Someone can help me to troubleshoot this issue ?

ENV: java8, itext7.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread on a similar question (about embedding, not subsetting, despite the OP's question): [How to subset fonts into an existing PDF file](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-subset-fonts-into-an-existing-PDF-file-td4656177.html).  The following statement is relevant:

> If you want to subset it, you'd need to parse all the content streams
>   in the PDF to find out which glyphs are used. That's NOT a trivial
>   task.

I wouldn't recommend attempting this in iText, unless it's really necessary.  It would likely end up buggy unless you have a very complete understanding of the PDF specs.  It might be worth pursuing other avenues such as changing the way the PDFs are created, or use something like Distiller that can do this for you.

If you do want to do this in iText, I'm afraid you will likely have to use a [PdfCanvasProcessor](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/index.html?com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/PdfCanvasProcessor.html) and some custom operator handlers.  You would need to find all text fields, determine which font they use, build a new subset font with the applicable glyphs, and replace the fonts with new subset copies.  This is how you would create a copy of the complete font to prepare for subsetting (assuming you don't have copies of the font files):

```
String encoding = PdfEncodings.WINANSI; // or another encoding if needed for more glyph support
PdfFont completeFont = ...; // get complete font from font dictionary
PdfFont subsetFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(completeFont.getFontProgram(), encoding, true);
subsetFont.setSubset(true);
```

When you encounter a Font change operator (`Tf`), you would need to look up that font in the font dictionary and create a new (or lookup an already created) subset copy of that font to prepare for upcoming text fields.  Don't forget to keep the font in a stack so you can pop back to the previous font (look for q and Q operators). And don't forget to check parent forms and page groups for the fonts if they don't exist in the current XObject or page resource dictionary.

When you encounter text (a `Tj`, `TJ`, `'`, or `"` operator), you would need to decode the text using the complete font, then re-encode it to the new subset font's encoding (unless you know for sure that all your source fonts are ASCII-compatible).  Add that text's characters to the subset like this:

```
subsetFont.addSubsetRange(new int[]{character});
```